# Dynamically load a class and its object in java

Tags: java, classloader, objectinputstream

I have a class file and a saved object of that class. My java application doesn't have that class in its libraries. When I tried to load the object using [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html), it gives an [ClassNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html).

Then I use the following code.

```
 URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{classFile.getParentFile().toURI().toURL()});
 classLoader.loadClass(classFile.getName().replace(".class", "")).newInstance();
 myClass= (MyClass) FileIOManager.readObject(classObj);
```

But this code also gives me the same exception when reading the object. Hope for a help to do my task..

**MyClass** doesn't have a package name.

**FileIOManager.readObject()** is a method I created to read a object and it works fine for other object which have classes inside my libraries.

Comment: Yon need to provide the full qualified name of the class, including the package(s). Otherwise, you will get this exception.

Comment: The class was created without a package name. I think that's not the problem..

Comment: Are you sure your ObjectInputStream is using your classloader? OIS has the tendency to ignore the current Thread's classloader and use the system classloader. Please verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `readObject()` method in `FileIOManager` class that I created to the following..

```
public static Serializable readObject(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return readObject(path, null);
}

public static Serializable readObject(String path, final ClassLoader classLoader) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Serializable obj;
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path); ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis) {

        @Override
        protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass desc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            if (classLoader == null) {
                return super.resolveClass(desc);
            }
            return Class.forName(desc.getName(), false, classLoader);
        }

    }) {
        obj = (Serializable) ois.readObject();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Here `path` is the path to the class file.

And get the object as follows.

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{classFile.getParentFile().toURI().toURL()});
myClass = (MyClass) FileIOManager.readObject(loc, classLoader);
```